# I can't make python check if a word is in a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

```
{rude_word = ['damn', 'hell', 'ass', 'piss', 'silly', 'idiotic']
    comment = input('Please comment on our service : ').lower()
    comment2 = comment.split(' ')
    if comment2 in rude_word:
        print("Cannot show [{}]".format(comment))
    else:
        print("Can show [{}]".format(comment))}
```

the desired result is
Please comment on our service : hell no
Cannot show [hell no]

Comment: First, your code is not written in Python: it is not correctly indented and is enclosed in odd curly braces. Second, `comment2` is a list of strings. A list of strings is never a member of another list of strings. Finally, `.split(' ')` is almost always wrong. Use `.split()` without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my comment to the post as such, you want to check if *any* word in question is on the list of stopwords. You should also convert the input to the lowercase or else there is no match.

```
if any(word.lower() in rude_word for word in comment.split()): ...
```

For performance purposes, organize the stopwords in a set, not in a list:

```
rude_word = {'damn', 'hell', 'ass', 'piss', 'silly', 'idiotic'}
```

The above modifications still do not protect you against other forms of profanities such as "idiot," "a$$," and even "asshole."